# Alternating Highlights when a value changes

Tags: excel

I have a data set like:

```
group       issues
1           bad
1           bad
2           good
3           bad
3           bad
3           bad
3           bad
4           bad
4           bad
5           bad
5           bad
6           good
```

I would like to highlight the bad groups, with a color for the whole group.  However if there are two bad groups in a row, I would like them to alternate colors, and have no color if it is a good group.  For example:

```
group       issues
1           bad  (blue)
1           bad  (blue)
2           good (white)
3           bad  (blue)
3           bad  (blue)
3           bad  (blue)
3           bad  (blue)
4           bad  (green)
4           bad  (green)
5           bad  (blue)
5           bad  (blue)
6           good (white)
```

For example.  The colors don't really matter.  Is there anyway to do this automatically for a fairly large data set?

Comment: Have you tried [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a macro like this:

```
Sub highlights()
Dim row
Dim AltColor As Integer
AltColor = 5
For row = 2 To 56
If Cells(row, 2).Value = "bad" Then
If Cells(row - 1, 1).Value <> Cells(row, 1).Value And Cells(row - 1,   Value = "bad" Then
If AltColor = 5 Then
     AltColor = 10
Cells(row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = AltColor
Else:
   AltColor = 5
   Cells(row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = AltColor
End If
Else
   Cells(row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = AltColor
End If
End If
Next row
End Sub
```

I suppose your data start from second row.numbers 5 and 10 refor to blue and green color.